# Design a 100 watt inverter, but why when the circuit is connected to the power supply sparks out?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, inverter, opto-isolator, boost

[image]
I'm making an inverter with 100 Watt power, 220 volt output voltage. The input voltage source of the inverter is from solar panels with a maximum voltage of 18 volts and a maximum current of 5.56 Amperes.

- This inverter circuit consists of a 150 Watt boost converter to increase the DC voltage of the solar panel to 24 Volts.
- Then the inverter circuit uses the P-channel IRF9540 and N-channel IRF540 mosfets, 4N35 mosfet drivers and BD139 transistors to amplify the frequency.
- To generate signals I use the Arduino SPWM program.
- The 24 VAC voltage will be raised to 220 volts with a 5A transformer and a 12-12 Volt voltage tap. The load for this inverter is the lamp and charger.

Before I connect directly to the solar panel. I first tested my circuit with a 16 Volt battery source, when I connected my circuit to the battery, sparks came out so that the input voltage decreased. Then I test by removing the Arduino pin from the circuit and still sparks come out. Is there something wrong with my circuit and what are the suggestions for this series? Is my circuit experiencing a short circuit? Thank you

Comment: sparks come out on the input section of the inverter when connected to the source @jsotola

Comment: sparks usually happen when there is a bad connection or when you connect or disconnect a wire while a circuit is drawing a fairly large current  .... were you manipulating wires when the sparks flew?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please define "the power supply sparks out". Where exactly? Did anything break? Is it inrush current due to large electrolytic capacitors on your boost converter?

Comment: sparks come out on the input of the inverter when connected to the source. I don't know about boost converter because I already bought boost converter module on the internet @winny

Comment: I have made the circuit on the PCB but the inverter input voltage still occurs decreases @jsotola

Comment: \$18V \times 5A = 90W\$  You'll **never** get 100 watts out of your inverter.

Comment: Still far from clear and you did not answer my questions. WHERE on the inverter? Did any component break?

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong, the maximum current of the solar panel is 5.56 A @JRE

Comment: so when the input part of the inverter is connected to the power supply, sparks come out in the input section of the inverter. So I mean "The power supply sparks out" and no component break @winny

Comment: "sparks out" is not an engineering term. Input section, is that your boost converter? What is your actual problem?

Comment: As Andy says - you are driving all MOSFET gates with excessive voltage. Vgs should NEVER be more than about say 15V (12V probably very adequate.) | Work out Vgs for each FET when drive is high and low - you need to redesign the driver so gate voltages are never excessive. THEN you need to look at shoot-through (see other comments) and also opto coupler speed. You could add an extra optocoupler per drive line so high and low drive has different optos and you can design Vgs to suit. IF you have 4 Arduino PWM lines available you could drive all FETs independently and elminate shoot through.

Answer (score 2):

> *This inverter circuit consists of a 150 Watt boost converter to
> increase the DC voltage of the solar panel to 24 Volts.*

[image]

From what I can see, with a 24 volts DC supply, Q3 and Q4 will see about 24 volts on their gates with respect to ground. This is significantly beyond the stated absolute maximum rating in the data sheet extract above.

I'm not ruling out other things (should those MOSFETs survive the first few seconds) such as: -

- MOSFET Shoot-through due to both MOSFETs on one side of the bridge simultaneously conducting as the (slow) gate drive switches.
- 1N4004 reverse recovery shoot-through (circa 30 us potentially)

Comment: What does it mean that the 24 volt input voltage is greater than the Vgs MOSFET IRF540 rating in the datasheet?

Comment: It means that the N channel IRF540 transistors will likely be damaged and go short circuit (normally).

Comment: so does the IRf540 mosfet need to be replaced with a higher Vgs rating? @Andy aka

Comment: Not really because you have reached the limit for most MOSFETs at 20 volts. Your basic circuit is weak in that as the MOSFETs switch (change over) you will have a high conductance path where both MOSFETs are on for a short period in each half of the H bridge. If you were trying to power a device of a few watts then this can be remedied or lived with but not when the load is 150 watts. You need proper MOSFET driver chips for 150 watts that have anti-shoot-through features and also protect the gate from receiving excessive voltage.

Comment: so is the 4n35 optocoupler as a mosfet driver that I have used yet it is not suitable for this circuit? @Andy aka

Comment: @NurAqmarina That's not at all what Andy said. I'm staring to beleve this project is above your head. Can you try to reduce the complexity and design and test just one thing at the time?

Comment: @NurAqmarina you need a proper MOSFET driver with anti-shoot-through protection and not an opto.

Comment: sorry i think mosfet driver you mean is optocoupler, thanks for the explanation you have given, very helpful @Andy aka

Comment: Go look up MOSFET drivers is my advice and, maybe tomorrow, if there are no better answers, please consider formally accepting this answer (or choose the better answer).

Comment: Well I followed the advice that you gave and have been looking for some IR2110, L293D and TC4420 mosfet drivers and those mosfet drivers are widely sold in my country. Then I thought of choosing the IR2110 mosfet driver and do you think this will suit my circuit? @Andy aka

Comment: Forget the L293D but the other two are  definitely in the right area to consider. Because you are using PMOS for the upper transistor you need to choose a device that can drive a high side PMOS fet. I don’t think (what is known as) a bootstrapped driver will work for your application.

Comment: @NurAqmarina did you forget something regarding my previous comment? [See this if you don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).